# How to Select distinct when muliple rows where one data is the same but the rest is different?

Tags: db2

I want to use select distinct where i have an ID and a DATE.
In my select there are multiple rows with the same ID but with different date, and this way the distinct doesn't work. My goal is to get every ID with the latest Date.

```
 Select distinct (ID), DATE from nagyleker order by DATE desc

result:
Table name: nagyleker

ID       DATE            
-------  -------------------  
6666666  2021-03-01 13:28:14  
0000004  2021-03-01 13:25:32  
3344454  2021-03-01 13:24:55  
3344454  2021-03-01 13:23:40  
6666666  2021-03-01 13:21:58  
1111120  2021-03-01 13:21:03  
0000008  2021-03-01 13:20:34  
0000009  2021-03-01 13:18:58

This was almost good, but i didnt get the latest values.


SELECT ID, MIN(DATE)
  FROM nagyleker
 GROUP BY ID
 ORDER BY MIN(DATE) DESC;
```

Can you help me with that?

Thank you guys for advance. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Replace your MIN with MAX.

```
SELECT ID, MAX(DATE) MAX_DATE
  FROM nagyleker
 GROUP BY ID
 ORDER BY MAX_DATE DESC;
```